# How to get external appSettings file name?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I have ASP.NET server app which has in web.config :

```
<appSettings file="config\another.config">
```

so the settings are different for each dev and stored separately in svn. is there a way to get the file name programmatically (I dont want to parse the web.config raw text just for that) ?

Comment: Is this what you want ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341906/read-custom-configuration-file-in-c-sharp-framework-4-0

Comment: no. he knows his filename. i am trying to find it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
String externalFilename = appSettingSection.File;
```

You will need to reference System.Web.Configuration for this.