# Best Settings Method to use for WinForms Plugin

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

All, I have a large C# application that I am writing a plugin for. I want to provide settings for this plugin and came to the conclusion that writing my own setting manager ect. and creating XML settings which would be put in the relevant special folders is the best way to go. However, I can't remember why (after coming back to project) I came to that conclusion over using the `Properties.Settings.MySetting` route. Can someone offer any advice in terms of what method is more preferable in my case?

Is writing my own overkill here, or is there a clear and obvious benefit?

I aplogise if I have asked this on the wrong Stack site.

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question and I'd like to let you know that you came to that decision because your DLL plugin cannot normally work with its own `app.config` file (where the settings are stored).

This happens because the [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) looks for app.config files attached to the executing process, which is main **exe** file.

You got several options over here, and the best one is to point the configuration manager which file to use as a config file which is greatly described at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341906/read-custom-configuration-file-in-c-sharp-framework-4-0).