# Read custom config file using custom config classes?

Tags: c#, config, configurationmanager

There are several [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341906/read-custom-configuration-file-in-c-sharp-framework-4-0) about reading [custom config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files) but none of them address using custom config sections. Here is a section from my app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="DatabaseConfigSection" type="Bootstrapper.DatabaseConfig, Bootstrapper" />
    </configSections>
    <DatabaseConfigSection>
        <Configuration>
            <Databases>
                <Database name="Database_Dev" environment="Dev"/>
                <Database name="Database_RC" environment="RC"/>
                <Database name="Database_Cloud" environment=""/>
            </Databases>
        </Configuration>
    </DatabaseConfigSection>
</configuration>
```

And I have a custom config class that allows me to code against it like this:

```
DatabaseConfig.Instance.Configuration.Databases.Cast<Database>().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

I want to have another, optional config file with the same structure as my app.config file above and I want to use my custom config class against it. For example, something like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.Use("otherConfigFile.config");
var new dbConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SectionSectionName) as DatabaseConfig;
dbConfig.Databases.Cast<Database>().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
```

And have it return the data from "otherConfigFile.config" as a `DatabaseConfig` object. However, I can't find a way to make `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` point to a different file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\Users\sirdank\project\bootstrapper\bin\Debug\test.config";
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
DatabaseConfig dbConfig = config.GetSection("DatabaseConfigSection") as DatabaseConfig;
```

Put together with the help of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx)

Comment: You would be far better off using config transforms, rather than putting all environments in one config.